# I used Bitcoin-QT to send BTC and it never confirmed. I used the zap command and resent with maximum fees, still no luck

Tags: bitcoin-core, unconfirmed-transactions

Hello I sent about $300 worth of BTC and it never got confirmed. I then used the `--zapwallettxes=1` command to get the BTC back and resend with max amount of fees, but it still didn't confirm on the other end. I tried this several times with different addresses, but nothing has worked. I can provide any details necessary to aid this process. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: The transaction ID is a5966f30e0b170e4d1af9b47dea6b8154022ef5917189890eef72e831e5dffab

Also Bitcoin-QT is now telling me that the transaction has 13 confirmations, however it still hasn't showed up in my other wallet. I searched for the transaction ID on blockchain.info, and see that the amount was successfully transferred to the address I intended it to. However, it then shows my BTC being transferred again to another address I didn't create. Does this mean my BTC was stolen?

[image: A screenshot of the slider on bitcoin-qt]

Comment: What does 'max amount of fees' mean? Bitcoin Core will let you send up to 0.1 BTC of fee. Even if you pay a high fee, transactions may take a while to confirm.

Comment: I used the "slider" on bitcoin-qt and pushed it all the way to the right, meaning the bitcoin would be confirmed within 1 block. I didn't manually type in an amount.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 2 blocks

Comment: Can you share the transaction ID?  Also, note that trying to hire someone to solve your problem isn't allowed on this site; it isn't for job recruiting.

Comment: I have added the transaction ID. My apologies for requesting payment, won't happen again.

Answer (score 1):

The fee you sent is 97 satoshi per byte, which is good enough to confirm your transaction with in 1 or 2 hours.

1 or 2 hours because there is a large number of unconfirmed transactions now. And several hundred transactions of them have a fee rate larger than your transaction's fee rate.

Your transaction should be confirmed now, please check it.